# A Java socket Server-Client 2 way chat program does not get expected result

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am new to Java NIO and I am using NIO2 to write a simple Server-Client 2 way communication program. Server and Client are running locally. I could not get the result of what I expected, could anyone help to check the code please? Thanks a lot.

Server side:

```
public class Server 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try (AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()) {

            server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2001));
            Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> acceptCon = server.accept();
            AsynchronousSocketChannel client = acceptCon.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if ((client != null) && (client.isOpen())) {
                Thread.sleep(50); // *** if I do not sleep 50 milsec here, I will get empty string
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                Future<Integer> readval = client.read(buffer);
                String msg = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
                System.out.println("Received from client: " + msg);

                readval.get();
                buffer.flip();
                String str = "I am fine! Thanks.";

                Future<Integer> writeVal = client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes()));
                System.out.println("Writing back to client: " + str);
                writeVal.get();
                buffer.clear();
            }
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Client 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        try (AsynchronousSocketChannel client = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open()) {

            Future<Void> result = client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2001));
            result.get();

            String str = "Hello! How are you?";
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes());
            Future<Integer> writeval = client.write(buffer);
            System.out.println("Writing to server: " + str);

            writeval.get();

            buffer.flip(); 


            Thread.sleep(100); // If I do not sleep 100 milsec here, most of the time, I will get empty string for svrMsg
            Future<Integer> readval = client.read(readBuffer);

            String svrMsg = new String(readBuffer.array()).trim();
            System.out.println("Received from server: " + svrMsg);
            readval.get();
            readBuffer.clear();
            buffer.clear();
        } catch (ExecutionException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Disconnected from the server.");
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get something like:
Server:

```
Received from client: Hello! How are you?
Writing back to client: I am fine! Thanks.
```

Client:

```
Writing to server: Hello! How are you?
Received from server: I am fine! Thanks.
```

But instead, I got:

```
Received from client: Hello! How are you? | (If do not use sleep, it is empty string here)
Writing back to client: I am fine! Thanks.
```

Client:

```
Writing to server: Hello! How are you?
Received from server: I am fine! Thanks.(If do not use sleep, empty string here)
```

My questions are:
1. I am using Eclipse, when I debug the server and client proj via breakpoints, I get the expected result. But when I run the server and the client, on the client side, if I do not use Thread.sleep(100), it will show empty string for "Received from server:", why? 
2. And for the server side, if I do not sleep for 50 milseconds, most of the time, the output of "Received from client: " will be empty string as well, any tips?

Thank you very much guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.read(buffer);` is an asynchronous operation. The `get` call on the future ensures that the operation has completed successfully.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
Future<Integer> readval = client.read(buffer);
readval.get();
String msg = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
System.out.println("Received from client: " + msg);
```